# why pytorch is not installing on windows 11 on python 3.11

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, torch, torchvision

I am trying to install pytorch on Windows 11 for quite some time now. I have upgraded pip and everything can someone help me with it?
python version 3.11.1 64 bit installed

I tried upgrading pip
I tried giving it the proper URL
I tried specifying version of it
NOTHING WORKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pytorch does not currently support python 3.11 on their main release branch[[1]](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/86566).

Easy route:
You should consider using a python version released prior 3.11 (ex. 3.10[[3]](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3109/)).

Medium route:
Install pytorch from their nightly release, it supports python 3.11[[2]](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/86566#issuecomment-1419472838)